# reducing depressed quartic to cubic polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

Recently I found this lovely *algebraic equation solver* flowchart online. What I do not understand is how to get from the Depressed Quartic (top right) to the Monic Cubic polynomial (the path where $\alpha_1 \neq 0$). I see that the intermediate equation $(u^2+[\alpha_2+y])^2=\dots$ is basically equivalent to the depressed quartic equation, but the next step is a mystery. What exactly do I have to do there? Is the $y$ in this equation the same as the one in th emonic cubic polynomial?

[image]

Comment: *"Choose y to make it a perfect square ..."* gives the cubic equation for y.

Comment: Ah, so we chose $y$ such that $\delta_1^2-4\delta_2\delta_0=0$, therefore the $y$ in the monic cubic equation is the $u$ in the depressed quartic equation, is it? What does it mean to 'make it a *perfect square*'?

Comment: In this context, a "perfect square" is a polynomial which is the square of another polynomial, e.g. a second order polynomial of the form $(au+b)^2$.

Comment: What is the source please?

Comment: @NoChance It was posted on reddit a while ago, unfortunately the user no longer exists: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2679hf/algebraic_quartic_equation_solver_diagram/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A nice approach indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arbitrary $y$, you have

$$
(u^2+[\alpha_2+y])^2= \delta_2 u^2 + \delta_1 u + \delta_0
$$
with
$$
   \delta_2 = \alpha_2 + 2y, \delta_1 = -\alpha_1, \delta_0 = [\alpha_2+y]^2 - \alpha_0 \quad .
$$
Now $y$ is determined such that $\delta_1^2 - 4 \delta_2 \delta_0 = 0$,
this gives a cubic equation for $y$.

If you substitute this solution $y$ back into the first equation, the
right-hand side becomes a "perfect square"

$$
(u^2+[\alpha_2+y])^2= \frac 1{4\delta_0}(\delta_1 u + 2\delta_0) ^2
$$
and you can proceed by taking square roots:
$$
u^2+[\alpha_2+y] = \pm \frac 1{2\sqrt{\delta_0}}(\delta_1 u + 2\delta_0)
$$